# How I read file into dictionary then sort and add index?

Tags: python, dictionary

If the file looks like this:

```
SID,Grade
1,99
2,100
3,55
4,60
```

how can I read it into python and turn the result like this:

```
Dict=readGrades(’grades.csv’)
```

Read 100 values.

```
gDict{’1’:99,  ’2’:100,  ’3’:55, ...}
```

Then sort the grades with rank

```
computeRank(gDict)
gDict{’1’:(99,2),’2’:(100,1),’3’:(55,4), ...}
```

Comment: What did you try? What did not work as expected?

Comment: Python has module  dedicated to handle csv files "https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html" . Second things standard dict's are not sorted as I remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def readGrades(filename):
    result = dict()
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            key, val = line.split(",")
            result[key] = int(val.strip())
    return result

def computeRank(dic):
    rank = sorted(list(dic.values())); rank.reverse()
    for key in dic.keys():
        dic[key] = (dic[key], rank.index(dic[key]))
```

you can try like this